# Parse RSS pubDate to Date object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, object, rss, parsing

How would I do this?

Tue, 2 Feb 2010 19:34:21 Etc/GMT

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It works right out of the box. The Date object in JavaScript can be set by passing a number of standard time formats. The format used in RSS is one of these.

Example:

```
var pubDate = "Sun, 27 Mar 2011 20:17:21 +0100";
var date = new Date(pubDate);

var months = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
var string = date.getDate() + " " + months[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear()

alert(string);
```

Comment: If the format includes the UTC designator (e.g. Sun, 25 Mar 2012 18:27:10Z), Safari (v 5.1.5) will return a null for Date.parse.  Other browsers do not.